# Index-Match returning value in cell above desired value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a couple index matches going on in a workbook I'm playing with. I basically have a huge lists of addresses in a table and I'm trying to pull specific ones to get mailing codes. I index match the names and cities of the organization to pull two mailing codes to my list which works just fine, then just to double check it I use those mail codes I pulled over to index/match the name and city from the big list I have so we can check for accuracy etc. The name and cities it is pulling are for the row above what I'm looking for and I'm not sure why it isn't pulling what I need.

The formula is as follows:

```
{=INDEX(Table1[#All], MATCH(1,(Table1[Code 2]=D17)*(Table1[Code max]=E17),0),1)}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Table1[#All]` includes the headers, `Table1[Code 2]` and `Table1[Code max]` do not. Instead of `Table1[#All]` just use `Table1`.